# How I reflect List<T> of Class<T> and get the content of T?

Tags: java, reflection

I have some questions when I reflect genericType.First of all,I have a class declaration like this:

```
public class JoyPageWebDTO<T> {
    private int recordCount;
    private int pageSize;
    private int pageIndex;
    private List<T> records;
}
```

And T is：

```
public class AuditSpuWebDTO implements Serializable {
    private String indications;
    private String forbidden;
    private int shopID;
    private String shopName;
    private String city;
    private Date updateTime;
    private int auditStatus;
    private String auditContent;
}
```

The result of JoyPageWebDTO after request like this:
     [https://i.stack.imgur.com/zeK1O.jpg][1]

The question is how can I get the T(`AuditSpuWebDTO`) from `JoyPageWebDTO`? I want's get the value of `AuditSpuWebDTO`.I wrote some code as following to deal this,however,failed!

```
public static void reflect(Class<?> clazz) {
    for (Field field : clazz.getDeclaredFields()) {
        //get the static type of the field
        Class<?> fieldType = field.getType();
        //if it's String,
        if (fieldType == String.class) {
            // save/use field
        }
        //if it's String[],
        else if (fieldType == String[].class) {
            // save/use field
        }
        //if it's List or a subtype of List,
        else if (List.class.isAssignableFrom(fieldType)) {
            //get the type as generic
            ParameterizedType fieldGenericType = (ParameterizedType) field.getGenericType();
            //get it's first type parameter
            Type type = fieldGenericType.getActualTypeArguments()[0];
            Class<?> fieldTypeParameterClazz;
            if (type instanceof ParameterizedType) {
                fieldTypeParameterClazz = (Class<?>) ((ParameterizedType) type).getRawType();
            } else if(type instanceof TypeVariable){
                //todo how to get the class????
            }else{
                fieldTypeParameterClazz = (Class<?>) type;
            }
            //if the type parameter is String,
            if (fieldTypeParameterClazz == String.class) {
                // save/use field
            }
        }
    }
}
```

When I reflect about the generic type:T from List,the type of the result is `TypeVariable`,how can I get the `Class<?>` from `TypeVariable`? The `todo` which I mark is the key crucial problem I have.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Get generic type of class at runtime](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3403909/get-generic-type-of-class-at-runtime)

Comment: Quick answer: not possible.

Answer (score 0):

The only thing `List` knows about it's generic type is that it has a name `T`

As Java uses type erasure, it's not possible to obtain this information at runtime. What is possible to obtain is when you have a specific type compiled into the class e.g.

```
// create a subclass of ArrayList with a specific type.
List<String> list = new ArrayList<String>() { };
```

However, a plain `List` or `ArrayList` has no type compiled into that class so its not possible to retrieve any more information from it.